# Editor with Java / JSP and CSS Code Hinting & Completion

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, dreamweaver, code-hinting

Im a Dreamweaver & Eclipse user. Dreamweaver for HTML & CSS development & Eclipse for heavy Java development. For JSP, Im currently using Dreamweaver. None of these tools would be used with a Web Server / Servlet Container.

I am looking for a Editor or Plugin that works in either Dreamweaver or Eclipse to to the following:

1. Working with Java Code in JSP - needs to code hint / complete Java code within the <% %> block for the entire Java libraries / classes defined in my machine.
2. It should also support HTML and CSS Code hinting / completion as well.

My aim is to either use 1 Editor at a time with the highest efficiency. I Do not use any Tag libraries, just old school JSP calling Java codes.

At the moment, my development relies on getting the code right in Eclipse (due to the good auto complete feature) and copy - paste the code to Dreamweaver and completing the HTML parts.

I have no problems to buy an Editor with these features

Thanks for your time. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does provide HTML and CSS code hinting / completion. Have a look at [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse EE is ok. Just set the right project facet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend JetBrains' IntelliJ.  It's the best Java IDE on the market.

Comment: i agreed with duffymo... and if you are using Eclipse for "heavy" Java development than lets together make a plugin for eclipse which could help your motive and several others. Tell me if anyone interested in this.